# Why some paths with double back slash throw Could not find a part of the path exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example this path and file is fine not exceptions : "E:\Samsung Galaxy S9\Danny Backup\Recovered data 02-10 18_32_36\1  (D) NTFS\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-006\Image-Downloader\Downloading-File-Project-Version-005\Download File\Downloading File\Downloading File\About.cs"

but then on another path of a file it's throwing exception Could not find a part of the path :

Could not find a part of the path "E:\Samsung Galaxy S9\Danny Backup\Recovered data 02-10 18_32_36\1  (D) NTFS\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-006\Image-Downloader\Downloading-File-Project-Version-005\Download File\Downloading File\Downloading File\FileDownload_Test.Designer.cs"

I checked manual in File Explorer moved to this path and the file there is exist and I can edit the file with notepad.

I also tried to in the File Explorer to get to the path with double back slash and it didn't find the path :

[image: Not found]

but if I delete one back slash it will find the path it will get to the path.
if I try to get to the path including the file name it will throw me message in the File Explorer that the path is longer then 269 chars.

sand when looking in the StackTrace of the exception I see :

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
>      at Search_Text_In_Files.Form1.DirSearch(String rootDirectory, String filesExtension, String[] textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e) in E:\Samsung Galaxy S9\Danny Backup\Recovered data 02-10 18_32_36\1  (D) NTFS\C-Sharp\Search_Text_In_Files\Search_Text_In_Files\Search_Text_In_Files\Form1.cs:line 275

Line 275 is :

```
var tempFR = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

I don't understand what is the problem with the file FileDownload_Test.Designer.cs why the first file About.cs was fine and the second give the exception. both files exists and can be edited/open.

I'm confused. maybe in the File Explorer I can get to the files but in the program for some reason it can't ?

```
int numberofdirs = 0;
        void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string[] textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            try
            {
                filePathList = SearchingCore.SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(rootDirectory, null, worker, e,_isbackgroundbusy,
                    textBoxSetFileExtensions, lblretrievedfiles,lblrestrictedfiles).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }
            lblphases.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        lblphases.Text = "Phase 2: Searching in files";
                    });
            MyProgress myp = new MyProgress();
            myp.Report4 = filePathList.Count.ToString();
            foreach (string file in filePathList)
            {
                try
                {
                    var tempFR = File.ReadAllText(file);

                    _isbackgroundbusy.WaitOne();
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    bool reportedFile = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (tempFR.IndexOf(textToSearch[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            if (!reportedFile)
                            {
                                numberoffiles++;

                                myp.Report1 = file;
                                myp.Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString();
                                myp.Report3 = textToSearch[i];
                                myp.Report5 = FindWordsWithCountRegex(tempFR, textToSearch).ToString();
                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, myp);
                                reportedFile = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    numberofdirs++;
                    lblsearchedfiles.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        lblsearchedfiles.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", numberofdirs, myp.Report4);
                        lblsearchedfiles.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    string fff = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is relevant, but it's worth checking out. https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The About.cs file full path is 244 characters long.
The FileDownload_Test.Designer.cs file is 265 characters long.

Your path to File.ReadAllText() must not be longer than 260 characters.